# Como hacer para que el admin de Django me cargue un combo-box , según uno anterior

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-admin

En la base de datos tengo info sobre comunas, barrios, etc, los cuales estan relacionados pero necesito que cuando seleccione una comuna me muestre los barrios pertenecientes a ellas :)

Tengo estos modelos en la clase geolocalizacion.

```
@admin.register(DivisionTerritorial)
class DivisionTerritorialAdmin(BaseImportExportModelAdmin):
    """
    Administrador modelo DivisionTerritorial
    """
    search_fields = ['nombre']
    list_filter = ['municipio', 'tipo_division']
    list_display = ['nombre', 'tipo_division', 'municipio', 'fecha_creacion', 'fecha_modificacion', 'fecha_eliminacion']
    readonly_fields = [
        'creado_por',
        'fecha_creacion',
        'ip_creacion',
        'modificado_por',
        'fecha_modificacion',
        'ip_modificacion',
        'eliminado_por',
        'fecha_eliminacion',
        'ip_eliminacion'
    ]
    resource_class = DivisionTerritorialResource
    fieldsets = (
        (
            None, {
                'classes': ('suit-tab suit-tab-general',),
                'fields': (
                   'nombre', 'tipo_division', 'municipio', 'fecha_creacion', 'fecha_modificacion', 'fecha_eliminacion'
                )
            }
        ), 
    )
    inlines = [BarrioInline,] 
    suit_form_tabs = (
        ('general', _('Divisiones territoriales')),
        ('Barrio', _('Barrio')),
    )

@admin.register(Barrio)
class BarrioAdmin(BaseImportExportModelAdmin):
    """
    Administrador modelo Barrio
    """
    search_fields = ['nombre']
    list_filter = ['municipio', 'zona_ubicacion']
    suit_list_filter_horizontal = ('municipio', 'zona_ubicacion')
    list_display = ['nombre', 'municipio', 'division_territorial', 'zona_ubicacion',
                     'latitud', 'longitud', 'fecha_creacion', 'fecha_modificacion', 'fecha_eliminacion']
    fields = ['nombre', 'zona_ubicacion', 'municipio', 'division_territorial', 'latitud', 'longitud',
              'fecha_creacion', 'fecha_modificacion','fecha_eliminacion']
    readonly_fields = [
        'creado_por',
        'fecha_creacion',
        'ip_creacion',
        'modificado_por',
        'fecha_modificacion',
        'ip_modificacion',
        'eliminado_por',
        'fecha_eliminacion',
        'ip_eliminacion'
    ]
    raw_id_fields = ['municipio']
    resource_class = BarrioResource
```

Estan unidos por una Fk y necesito que cuando los llame en otro modelo estos aparezcan según la fk anterior.

[image: 1]

Entonces necesito que si elijo un Departamento en la siguiente casilla me liste los municipios pertenecientes a ese departamento.
Vi en todo lado que se podría realizar con Ajax pero no se como usarlo aquí en el admin, muchas gracias!

Comment: En efecto, deberías hacerlo con una petición ajax desde la vista del admin. Podrías hacer un override de la plantilla para incluir el código js necesario o bien cargar un js externo en el ModelAdmin que estés usando. ¿Qué has probado?

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder :)
Soy nuevo en esto, solo e usado Django admin site para todo, por lo que no se como crear ese overide en el admin, me podrias indicar desde el admin como realizo la peticion?, muchas gracias :)